# iOS AudioKit: How to observe currently elapsed time while recording

Tags: ios, audiokit

I'm using `AudioKit` for recording and playback purposes in my app. I'm wanting to reflect the current elapsed recording time from the `AKNodeRecorder` so the user can see how long the recording is in real time. How can I accomplish this?

There are no delegate or callback functions exposed, and KVO isn't an option because the value I want to observer `recordedDuration` isn't `@objc` annonated. Is this possible or do I need to approach this from a different angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After combing through the source, I came across this class `AKPeriodicFunction`, which is passed in the `AudioKit.start()` call. This will fire a closure at a given interval so you can do whatever.